# UITableView first row '0' wont update upon table reload - all others do?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have a one view app with embedded UITableView that displays a list of "stores"(Realm object). By default I populate the table view of all the Store objects. IF the user wants to then narrow the results they can do so by using any combination of text fields in MasterVC. When they hit search - simply *update* TableView with 'filtered' Realm objects.

What works:

- Populate UITableView with objects from the Realm.
- Create new Realm entries via text field entries in MasterVC and repopulate table in ResultsVC.
- Swipe to delete object on table / and Realm object.

What sort of works:

- If user enters a search term then 'filter' the Realm object (Stores) and repopulate the table. This correctly reloads and returns the number of results. **However** the *First Cell (0)* of the TableView is *always* the exact same and never updates.. If there are 20 returned results in the search then Rows 1-18 are correctly displayed. Row 0 is static and never changes its text. Any obvious reasons why?

**Results Table View Controller**

```
class ResultsVC: UITableViewController {

    // data source
    var stores: Results<Store> = {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        return realm.objects(Store.self)
    }()

    var token: NotificationToken?

    ...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return stores.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ResultsCustomViewCell

        let stores = realm.objects(Store.self)
        let currentStore = stores[indexPath.row]
        cell.storeNumber.text = "#\(currentStore.storeNumber)"
        cell.storeName.text = "\"\(currentStore.storeName)\""
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm accessing the **ResultsVC** from **MasterVC**

**Master View Controller**

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    @IBAction func searchDatabase(_ sender: Any) {
        let CVC = childViewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
        let resultVC = CVC.viewControllers[0] as? ResultsVC
        result.stores = stores.filter("address = '1234 Blue Street'")
        result.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in cell For Row at Index Path, what values do you see for row 0? Are they new values, but the actual cell fields are not being updated (somehow)?

Comment: You should also share your code on `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. Or investigate on it yourself. The info you current provided is not enough.

Comment: @OwenZhao that was it. Overlooked it a hundred times. Overwriting the original 'stores' variable by mistake. Removed `let stores = realm.objects(Store.self)` and works like it should. If you want to add as answer Ill accept it. Thanks.

Comment: It is OK. Glad to know you had your answer. Please add the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had a duplicate variable which was overwriting the orig from above.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ResultsCustomViewCell

    let stores = realm.objects(Store.self) // <- OVERWRITING ORIGINAL //
    let currentStore = stores[indexPath.row]
    cell.storeNumber.text = "#\(currentStore.storeNumber)"
    cell.storeName.text = "\"\(currentStore.storeName)\""
    return cell
}
```